# How to execute Docker query command on all containers?

Tags: docker

In docker I can make `docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" CONTAINER` to run command on a particular container.

What I need is to do something like 
`docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" all` or
`docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" *`
to run a command on all containers, not mentioning their names explicitly?

It relates to other docker commands as well. Is there such a way without bash scripting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can list multiple container to a [`docker inspect`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#inspect).

```
docker inspect [OPTIONS] CONTAINER|IMAGE [CONTAINER|IMAGE...]
```

But the only way to list those container is through bash `$(sudo docker ps -aq)`.

For example:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Name}}' $(sudo docker ps -aq)
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" $(sudo docker ps -aq)
```

The [OP f1yegor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3092405/f1yegor) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070027/docker-query-command-on-all-containers/30070411#comment48296534_30070411):

```
all=$(sudo docker ps -aq) docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" $all
```

Comment: I was looking for a container that was using a volume, your command worked a treat (with added grep for my use case): `sudo docker inspect $(sudo docker ps -aq) | grep -B100 4c35ea | grep Name`